# In Microsoft Excel how are single quotes applied to the sheet name in a formula?

Tags: excel

Whilst working with Microsoft Excel, I created a very big formula which has many symbols, and its total string length is about 8047 in Excel 2007. When I researched I saw that the maximum number of characters allowed for a formula is 8129.

I extracted the Excel file and I could see that the Microsoft Excel is applying single quotes (`''`) before the sheet name, and it varies: for some sheet names there are single quotes but for others, there are no quotes.

Can anyone explain why this is?

I have given below the formula that was represented in the Excel spreadsheet.

```
SUM(╟!$C$34+╟!$G$26:$K$29+╚!$B$40+╚!$G$33:$K$38+╔!$D$38+╔!$F$35:$I$37+╩!$C$39+╩!$D$36:$F$40+╦!$E$36+╦!$D$37:$F$39+╠!$E$38+╠!$K$24:$M$35+═!$E$40+═!$H$35:$J$39+╬!$I$33+╬!$L$23:$N$33+╧!$F$40+╧!$K$25:$L$35+╨!$G$39+╨!$L$23:$M$34+╤!$G$40+╤!$K$27:$M$38+╥!$G$39+╥!$J$31:$L$37+╙!$H$39+╙!$J$28:$L$39+╘!$H$39+╘!$J$28:$M$34+╒!$I$38+╒!$K$27:$M$38+╓!$H$40+╓!$J$24:$M$34+╫!$H$36+╫!$J$25:$L$38+╪!$I$35+╪!$K$24:$L$34+┘!$I$38+┘!$L$23:$M$34+┌!$I$37+┌!$K$24:$M$34+█!$I$39+█!$K$23:$M$35+▄!$J$38+▄!$K$27:$M$35+▌!$J$38+▌!$L$24:$N$34+'▐'!$J$41+'▐'!$J$30:$L$37+'▀'!$J$37+'▀'!$K$27:$M$38+ї!$G$39+ї!$K$28:$M$34+Ў!$G$41+Ў!$I$33:$J$39+°!$H$39+°!$K$27:$L$35+'∙'!$J$37+'∙'!$J$32:$K$37+·!$H$40+·!$I$29:$K$35+√!$I$39+√!$J$31:$K$38+¤!$I$38+¤!$I$31:$J$36+■!$I$39+■!$J$29:$K$36+' '!$J$34+' '!$J$26:$K$35,Cells!$A$1+Cells!$J$12:$L$15+'Merged Cells'!$A$1:$G$9+'Merged Cells'!$K$24+Styles!$A$1+Styles!$M$10:$M$21+'Row Column'!$A$1+'Row Column'!$L$7:$N$25+'@'!$A$2+'@'!$L$19:$M$31+'!'!$C$2+'!'!$M$10:$M$26+'~'!$H$37+'~'!$M$16:$P$30+'#'!$G$37+'#'!$L$17:$N$33+'$'!$F$35+'$'!$L$17:$M$30+'%'!$G$35+'%'!$L$16:$N$31+'^'!$G$37+'^'!$K$19:$N$32+'&'!$H$38+'&'!$L$17:$N$33+'()'!$H$37+'()'!$L$20:$N$36+'-'!$H$38+'-'!$L$18:$O$34+_!$G$37+_!$L$25:$N$34+'='!$H$36+'='!$K$29:$N$36+'+'!$I$34+'+'!$K$27:$M$35+'|'!$H$35+'|'!$I$32:$L$36+'{}'!$H$36+'{}'!$I$35:$L$38+'`'!$H$37+'`'!$J$33:$M$39+№!$I$36+№!$J$35:$M$39+';'!$G$38+';'!$H$37:$I$39+ё!$G$41+ё!$G$40:$L$44+'"'!$C$30+'"'!$C$30:$D$35+','!$G$39+','!$G$38:$J$39+'.'!$G$37+'.'!$H$35:$H$38+'<>'!$I$35+'<>'!$I$35:$K$36+'1'!$H$37+'1'!$H$36:$J$39+▲!$I$37+▲!$K$30:$L$39+'☺'!$H$36+'☺'!$I$34:$K$37+'☻'!$J$38+'☻'!$L$28:$M$34+♥!$I$37+♥!$K$27:$M$36+'♦'!$I$36+'♦'!$K$30:$M$35+♣!$I$37+♣!$K$34:$L$39+♠!$J$31+♠!$L$31:$N$39+'•'!$H$34+'•'!$I$30:$L$37+'◘'!$K$32+'◘'!$M$19:$O$29+○!$J$35+○!$K$29:$M$35+'◙'!$I$36+'◙'!$L$27:$N$34+♂!$K$32+♂!$M$26:$N$34+♪!$I$35+♪!$M$25:$O$35+♀!$K$34+♀!$L$28:$N$36+'♫'!$I$34+'♫'!$L$30:$M$36+'☼'!$J$37+'☼'!$K$29:$L$36+'►'!$J$39+'►'!$K$33:$M$38+'◄'!$J$38+'◄'!$L$27:$N$35+↕!$L$32+↕!$L$30:$N$36+'‼'!$J$38+'‼'!$K$31:$M$38+¶!$J$33+¶!$L$25:$N$33+§!$K$33+§!$L$25:$N$33+'▬'!$J$39+'▬'!$K$33:$M$38+'↨'!$J$34+'↨'!$L$29:$N$38+↑!$K$35+↑!$M$28:$N$36+↓!$K$37+↓!$L$25:$N$32+→!$L$32+→!$M$16:$P$28+←!$J$39+←!$K$30:$N$38+∟!$J$36+∟!$L$30:$M$36+∟!$J$39+∟!$L$29:$N$37+↔!$I$35+↔!$L$25:$N$30+▼!$J$31+▼!$L$27:$M$34+' '!$K$34+' '!$M$23:$O$33+'0'!$L$33+'0'!$L$31:$O$35+'░'!$J$36+'░'!$M$29:$N$38+▒!$J$39+▒!$K$30:$N$35+▓!$J$35+▓!$K$28:$N$35+│!$K$35+│!$M$29:$O$37+┤!$J$38+┤!$L$31:$N$37+╡!$J$38+╡!$L$31:$M$37+╢!$J$40+╢!$K$34:$M$37+╖!$J$38+╖!$K$33:$L$36+╕!$J$38+╕!$L$32:$M$38+╣!$J$38+╣!$K$24:$N$33+║!$J$38+║!$M$25:$O$36+╗!$J$39+╗!$L$27:$N$37+╝!$J$39+╝!$L$27:$N$38+╜!$J$38+╜!$M$30:$N$38+╛!$J$39+╛!$L$26:$O$37,╟!$C$34+╟!$G$26:$K$29+╚!$B$40+╚!$G$33:$K$38+╔!$D$38+╔!$F$35:$I$37+╩!$C$39+╩!$D$36:$F$40+╦!$E$36+╦!$D$37:$F$39+╠!$E$38+╠!$K$24:$M$35+═!$E$40+═!$H$35:$J$39+╬!$I$33+╬!$L$23:$N$33+╧!$F$40+╧!$K$25:$L$35+╨!$G$39+╨!$L$23:$M$34+╤!$G$40+╤!$K$27:$M$38+╥!$G$39+╥!$J$31:$L$37+╙!$H$39+╙!$J$28:$L$39+╘!$H$39+╘!$J$28:$M$34+╒!$I$38+╒!$K$27:$M$38+╓!$H$40+╓!$J$24:$M$34+╫!$H$36+╫!$J$25:$L$38+╪!$I$35+╪!$K$24:$L$34+┘!$I$38+┘!$L$23:$M$34+┌!$I$37+┌!$K$24:$M$34+█!$I$39+█!$K$23:$M$35+▄!$J$38+▄!$K$27:$M$35+▌!$J$38+▌!$L$24:$N$34+'▐'!$J$41+'▐'!$J$30:$L$37+'▀'!$J$37+'▀'!$K$27:$M$38+ї!$G$39+ї!$K$28:$M$34+Ў!$G$41+Ў!$I$33:$J$39+°!$H$39+°!$K$27:$L$35+'∙'!$J$37+'∙'!$J$32:$K$37+·!$H$40+·!$I$29:$K$35+√!$I$39+√!$J$31:$K$38+¤!$I$38+¤!$I$31:$J$36+■!$I$39+■!$J$29:$K$36+' '!$J$34+' '!$J$26:$K$35,Cells!$A$1+Cells!$J$12:$L$15+'Merged Cells'!$A$1:$G$9+'Merged Cells'!$K$24+Styles!$A$1+Styles!$M$10:$M$21+'Row Column'!$A$1+'Row Column'!$L$7:$N$25+'@'!$A$2+'@'!$L$19:$M$31+'!'!$C$2+'!'!$M$10:$M$26+'~'!$H$37+'~'!$M$16:$P$30+'#'!$G$37+'#'!$L$17:$N$33+'$'!$F$35+'$'!$L$17:$M$30+'%'!$G$35+'%'!$L$16:$N$31+'^'!$G$37+'^'!$K$19:$N$32+'&'!$H$38+'&'!$L$17:$N$33+'()'!$H$37+'()'!$L$20:$N$36+'-'!$H$38+'-'!$L$18:$O$34+_!$G$37+_!$L$25:$N$34+'='!$H$36+'='!$K$29:$N$36+'+'!$I$34+'+'!$K$27:$M$35+'|'!$H$35+'|'!$I$32:$L$36+'{}'!$H$36+'{}'!$I$35:$L$38+'`'!$H$37+'`'!$J$33:$M$39+№!$I$36+№!$J$35:$M$39+';'!$G$38+';'!$H$37:$I$39+ё!$G$41+ё!$G$40:$L$44+'"'!$C$30+'"'!$C$30:$D$35+','!$G$39+','!$G$38:$J$39+'.'!$G$37+'.'!$H$35:$H$38+'<>'!$I$35+'<>'!$I$35:$K$36+'1'!$H$37+'1'!$H$36:$J$39+▲!$I$37+▲!$K$30:$L$39+'☺'!$H$36+'☺'!$I$34:$K$37+'☻'!$J$38+'☻'!$L$28:$M$34+♥!$I$37+♥!$K$27:$M$36+'♦'!$I$36+'♦'!$K$30:$M$35+♣!$I$37+♣!$K$34:$L$39+♠!$J$31+♠!$L$31:$N$39+'•'!$H$34+'•'!$I$30:$L$37+'◘'!$K$32+'◘'!$M$19:$O$29+○!$J$35+○!$K$29:$M$35+'◙'!$I$36+'◙'!$L$27:$N$34+♂!$K$32+♂!$M$26:$N$34+♪!$I$35+♪!$M$25:$O$35+♀!$K$34+♀!$L$28:$N$36+'♫'!$I$34+'♫'!$L$30:$M$36+'☼'!$J$37+'☼'!$K$29:$L$36+'►'!$J$39+'►'!$K$33:$M$38+'◄'!$J$38+'◄'!$L$27:$N$35+↕!$L$32+↕!$L$30:$N$36+'‼'!$J$38+'‼'!$K$31:$M$38+¶!$J$33+¶!$L$25:$N$33+§!$K$33+§!$L$25:$N$33+'▬'!$J$39+'▬'!$K$33:$M$38+'↨'!$J$34+'↨'!$L$29:$N$38+↑!$K$35+↑!$M$28:$N$36+↓!$K$37+↓!$L$25:$N$32+→!$L$32+→!$M$16:$P$28+←!$J$39+←!$K$30:$N$38+∟!$J$36+∟!$L$30:$M$36+∟!$J$39+∟!$L$29:$N$37+↔!$I$35+↔!$L$25:$N$30+▼!$J$31+▼!$L$27:$M$34+' '!$K$34+' '!$M$23:$O$33+'0'!$L$33+'0'!$L$31:$O$35+'░'!$J$36+'░'!$M$29:$N$38+▒!$J$39+▒!$K$30:$N$35+▓!$J$35+▓!$K$28:$N$35+│!$K$35+│!$M$29:$O$37+┤!$J$38+┤!$L$31:$N$37+╡!$J$38+╡!$L$31:$M$37+╢!$J$40+╢!$K$34:$M$37+╖!$J$38+╖!$K$33:$L$36+╕!$J$38+╕!$L$32:$M$38+╣!$J$38+╣!$K$24:$N$33+║!$J$38+║!$M$25:$O$36+╗!$J$39+╗!$L$27:$N$37+╝!$J$39+╝!$L$27:$N$38+╜!$J$38+╜!$M$30:$N$38+╛!$J$39+╛!$L$26:$O$37,╟!$C$34+╟!$G$26:$K$29+╚!$B$40+╚!$G$33:$K$38+╔!$D$38+╔!$F$35:$I$37+╩!$C$39+╩!$D$36:$F$40+╦!$E$36+╦!$D$37:$F$39+╠!$E$38+╠!$K$24:$M$35+═!$E$40+═!$H$35:$J$39+╬!$I$33+╬!$L$23:$N$33+╧!$F$40+╧!$K$25:$L$35+╨!$G$39+╨!$L$23:$M$34+╤!$G$40+╤!$K$27:$M$38+╥!$G$39+╥!$J$31:$L$37+╙!$H$39+╙!$J$28:$L$39+╘!$H$39+╘!$J$28:$M$34+╒!$I$38+╒!$K$27:$M$38+╓!$H$40+╓!$J$24:$M$34+╫!$H$36+╫!$J$25:$L$38+╪!$I$35+╪!$K$24:$L$34+┘!$I$38+┘!$L$23:$M$34+┌!$I$37+┌!$K$24:$M$34+█!$I$39+█!$K$23:$M$35+▄!$J$38+▄!$K$27:$M$35+▌!$J$38+▌!$L$24:$N$34+'▐'!$J$41+'▐'!$J$30:$L$37+'▀'!$J$37+'▀'!$K$27:$M$38+ї!$G$39+ї!$K$28:$M$34+Ў!$G$41+Ў!$I$33:$J$39+°!$H$39+°!$K$27:$L$35+'∙'!$J$37+'∙'!$J$32:$K$37+·!$H$40+·!$I$29:$K$35+√!$I$39+√!$J$31:$K$38+¤!$I$38+¤!$I$31:$J$36+■!$I$39+■!$J$29:$K$36+' '!$J$34+' '!$J$26:$K$35,Cells!$A$1+Cells!$J$12:$L$15+'Merged Cells'!$A$1:$G$9+'Merged Cells'!$K$24+Styles!$A$1+Styles!$M$10:$M$21+'Row Column'!$A$1+'Row Column'!$L$7:$N$25+'@'!$A$2+'@'!$L$19:$M$31+'!'!$C$2+'!'!$M$10:$M$26+'~'!$H$37+'~'!$M$16:$P$30+'#'!$G$37+'#'!$L$17:$N$33+'$'!$F$35+'$'!$L$17:$M$30+'%'!$G$35+'%'!$L$16:$N$31+'^'!$G$37+'^'!$K$19:$N$32+'&'!$H$38+'&'!$L$17:$N$33+'()'!$H$37+'()'!$L$20:$N$36+'-'!$H$38+'-'!$L$18:$O$34+_!$G$37+_!$L$25:$N$34+'='!$H$36+'='!$K$29:$N$36+'+'!$I$34+'+'!$K$27:$M$35+'|'!$H$35+'|'!$I$32:$L$36+'{}'!$H$36+'{}'!$I$35:$L$38+'`'!$H$37+'`'!$J$33:$M$39+№!$I$36+№!$J$35:$M$39+';'!$G$38+';'!$H$37:$I$39+ё!$G$41+ё!$G$40:$L$44+'"'!$C$30+'"'!$C$30:$D$35+','!$G$39+','!$G$38:$J$39+'.'!$G$37+'.'!$H$35:$H$38+'<>'!$I$35+'<>'!$I$35:$K$36+'1'!$H$37+'1'!$H$36:$J$39+▲!$I$37+▲!$K$30:$L$39+'☺'!$H$36+'☺'!$I$34:$K$37+'☻'!$J$38+'☻'!$L$28:$M$34+♥!$I$37+♥!$K$27:$M$36+'♦'!$I$36+'♦'!$K$30:$M$35+♣!$I$37+♣!$K$34:$L$39+♠!$J$31+♠!$L$31:$N$39+'•'!$H$34+'•'!$I$30:$L$37+'◘'!$K$32+'◘'!$M$19:$O$29+○!$J$35+○!$K$29:$M$35+'◙'!$I$36+'◙'!$L$27:$N$34+♂!$K$32+♂!$M$26:$N$34+♪!$I$35+♪!$M$25:$O$35+♀!$K$34+♀!$L$28:$N$36+'♫'!$I$34+'♫'!$L$30:$M$36+'☼'!$J$37+'☼'!$K$29:$L$36+'►'!$J$39+'►'!$K$33:$M$38+'◄'!$J$38+'◄'!$L$27:$N$35+↕!$L$32+↕!$L$30:$N$36+'‼'!$J$38+'‼'!$K$31:$M$38+¶!$J$33+¶!$L$25:$N$33+§!$K$33+§!$L$25:$N$33+'▬'!$J$39+'▬'!$K$33:$M$38+'↨'!$J$34+'↨'!$L$29:$N$38+↑!$K$35+↑!$M$28:$N$36+↓!$K$37+↓!$L$25:$N$32+→!$L$32+→!$M$16:$P$28+←!$J$39+←!$K$30:$N$38+∟!$J$36+∟!$L$30:$M$36+∟!$J$39+∟!$L$29:$N$37+↔!$I$35+↔!$L$25:$N$30+▼!$J$31+▼!$L$27:$M$34+' '!$K$34+' '!$M$23:$O$33+'0'!$L$33+'0'!$L$31:$O$35+'░'!$J$36+'░'!$M$29:$N$38+▒!$J$39+▒!$K$30:$N$35+▓!$J$35+▓!$K$28:$N$35+│!$K$35+│!$M$29:$O$37+┤!$J$38+┤!$L$31:$N$37+╡!$J$38+╡!$L$31:$M$37+╢!$J$40+╢!$K$34:$M$37+╖!$J$38+╖!$K$33:$L$36+╕!$J$38+╕!$L$32:$M$38+╣!$J$38+╣!$K$24:$N$33+║!$J$38+║!$M$25:$O$36+╗!$J$39+╗!$L$27:$N$37+╝!$J$39+╝!$L$27:$N$38+╜!$J$38+╜!$M$30:$N$38+╛!$J$39+╛!$L$26:$O$37)/╫!K6
```

Answer (score 4):

I think the formula limit applies to the R1C1 version of the formula, which is usually longer than the A1 version you are showing, so you are probably over the limit anyway.

Sheet names are surrounded by single quotes when they contain a space (and possibly other strange characters).

But anyway my advice would be to break this monster formula up into a large number of smaller ones in separate cells. Megaformulae like this are very hard to understand, test and debug.

Charles

Answer (score 2):

As Charles Williams suggests it is the space in the Sheet name.
If you explained what you are trying to do in this formula, it most likely could be simplified.